# How to display a QLabel under another QLabel?

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyside, qlabel

I have some QLabels in a QWindow. They might have some space in common. I want to know how can I change label's depth. In default situation the label which defined later is on the previews ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an indent for each widget and call `raise_` function in sort of their indent.

```
for label in labels:
    label.raise_()
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use raise, like :
labelname.raise_()

Answer (score 0):

All widgets have methods for this.

```
widget.stackUnder(another_widget) #relative postition

widget.lower() # send to the bottom
widget.raise_() # send to the top
```

See documentation on QWidget